# How can I use acumatica custom attribute in Event Handler?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need to use my custom attribute to trigger an event, in this case I need usrTextileItem==true to trigger usrTextileItemType Field to visible=true.

here's my Declaration in Extension for Textile Item

```
[PXBool]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Textile Item")]
```

here's my Declaration in Extension for Textile Item Type

```
[PXDBString(1)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Textile Item Type", Visible=false)]
[PXDefault("C")]
[PXStringList(
new string[]{
"C","Y","B","F"   
},
new string[]{
"Cotton", "Yarn","Beam","Finish Goods"
})]
```

and this is my current `InventroyMaint__Extension`

```
protected void InventoryItem_UsrTextileItem_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{

  InventoryItem row = (InventoryItem)e.Row;
  InventoryItemExt ext = cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();

 if(ext.usrTextileItem==true){ 
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<InventoryItemExt.usrTextileItemType>(cache, row, true);
 }

}
```

and I can't get the extensions value, and I have 3 error that says:
First error:

> 'PX.Data.PXCache' does not contain a definition for 'GetExtension' and
>   the best extension method overload
>   'PX.Data.PXCacheEx.GetExtension(PX.Data.IBqlTable)' has some invalid
>   arguments in file: Code#InventoryItemMaint(37)
>
> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'PX.Data.PXCache' to
>   'PX.Data.IBqlTable' in file: Code#InventoryItemMaint(37)
>
> 'usrTextileItem': cannot reference a type through an expression; try
>   'PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt.usrTextileItem' instead in file:
>   Code#InventoryItemMaint(39)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't compile, but even if it did, it wouldn't work. `SetVisible`, `SetEnabled` or any other call affecting UI shouldn't be done from FieldUpdated event. You should do it from `RowSelected` instead. This is covered during in the developer training materials; I suggest you review how events work and in which order they're processed when you change value and do a callback.

P.S. `cache.GetExtension<T>();` expects a parameter - replace it with `cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(row);`